# adding a statement after or before all specific function calls using define in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have done this before but somehow I can't do it now so I ask here.
I have some codes I downloaded from a git repository and I want to print the filename, and linenumber whenever malloc is called. I made a simple test.

```
---- test.c ----
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "xxx.h"

main()
{
printf("hello\n");
int *ip = malloc(120*sizeof(int));
printf("ip = %x\n",ip);
free(ip);
}

---- xxx.h
#define malloc(x) do {malloc(x); \
printf("malloc at %s()-%d,%s\n",__func__,__LINE__,__FILE__);} \
while(0)
```

When I do `gcc test.c`, I get

```
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:8: error: expected expression before 'do'
```

How should I fix xxx.h ?  (this question applies also for C++)

Comment: where is `;` before the `do`?

Comment: you forgot some \

Comment: Never use a macro where a function or a function call wrapped in a macro will do as well.

Comment: You probably didn't include stdlib.h. Btw, using the same identifiers as those present in the standard libraries is not allowed by C.

Comment: @Lundin, I want to leave malloc(..) intact in the original codes but overload it to do malloc plus some other task(printing here). Isn't it possible?

Comment: @ChanKim Strictly speaking, I believe that the C language forbids this through 7.1.3. It may or may not work on some compilers but it probably won't be portable.

Comment: Please write in modern C, not archaic C.  All functions need an explicit return type — including `main()`.  You should write `int main(void)` every time (unless you use the command line arguments; then you use a variant on `int main(int argc, char **argv)`), and every other function definition should have an explicit type.  This is required by C99 and beyond.

Comment: @Lundin, but it should be noted we can modify the behavior of malloc() using #define using the answer by John Zwinck below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
#define malloc(x) ( \
    printf("malloc at %s()-%d,%s\n",__func__,__LINE__,__FILE__), \
    malloc(x))
```

The idea is to use the "comma operator" like this:

```
int *ip = (printf(...), malloc(120*sizeof(int)));
```

The result of the comma operator is always its last argument.

Comment: Note that, in theory, the `<stdlib.h>` header could have provided a macro for `malloc()`.  You might, therefore, need to `#undef malloc` before defining this macro.  The chances of running foul of this are minimal, but funnier things have been known.  I got burned by a macro definition for `snprintf()` once, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Given the macro, the line

```
int *ip = malloc(120*sizeof(int));
```

expands to

```
int *ip = do { malloc(120*sizeof(int)); printf("malloc at %s()-%d,%s\n",__func__,__LINE__,__FILE__);} while(0);
```

which hopefully makes it obvious where that error comes from.

John Zwinck's solution is a good option, although personally I'd create a wrapper function (named something other than `malloc`, naturally) rather than a macro.

Comment: A wrapper *function* cannot use `__func__`, `__LINE__` or `__FILE__` like this...